# Нужно спарсить данные из андроид приложения poizon

Tags: мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения

Нужно спарсить данные из андроид приложения poizon все кроссовки с определенным брендом, дошел до вытягивания запросов из brue suite, но дальше встал

Результат работы

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Нужна спарсить все товары( кроссовки jordan и поместить их в БД)